# switching between activities in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi I'm writing an app that has multiple activities. Right now it starts at the home screen, then when the user presses a button it starts a new activity and goes to another screen, then the user enters in information and presses a button to start another activity and another screen.

I have a menu setup so that from whatever the activity the user is in they can get back to the home screen. What I want it to do is kill all the current activities and just take the user right back to the home screen, so there is only one activity running again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If you add `myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` then when you run `startActivity(myIntent);` it clears all activities except the one myIntent is starting.

Answer (score 1):

After sending the `Intent` just call `finish()` and the activity you're leaving will be closed.

Just don't do that on your "homescreen" activity. That way whenever the user starts an activity through one of your activities when he presses the back hardware button he is going to get back to your "homescreen" activity.

Comment: Right, see I don't want that to happen. The user may need to get back to a previous activity, so I want the back button functional and able to return to previous activities. It's just the home button  in my menu that I want to kill all activities and return to the home screen and activity.